# USB wifi adapter is not being recognized and the manufacturer's driver won't compile. Netis WF2190

Tags: drivers, wireless, usb, connection

I have a Netis WF2190 and I'm trying to get it to work on Kubuntu 18.04. I have downloaded and tried installing the driver from Netis' website but it won't compile. [Output from the installation script can be found here](https://pastebin.com/29vCypHh).

I have tried emailing the Netis' USA support staff since Thursday two weeks ago and have not gotten any reply. I have tried contacting their international support and general inquiries teams but their inboxes were full. As a last resort, I have sent an email containing my woes to the sales inquiries team but I don't expect much since they can't seem to keep their website up for more than a few days a week.

What do I need to do to make my wifi adapter work?

[If you are lucky, you can download the driver from Netis' support site here.](http://www.netis-systems.com/Suppory/de_details/id/1/de/96.html)
[More than likely, you're going to have to download it from archive.org (here).](https://web.archive.org/web/20180224124225/http://www.netis-systems.com/Suppory/de_details/id/1/de/96.html)

The driver is listed for Ubuntu 16.04/4.4.0 and dated February 21st, 2017

Per @chili555's request, here's the output of `lsusb`:

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8001 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 0bda:8812 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8812AU 802.11a/b/g/n/ac WLAN Adapter
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8009 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 003: ID 0480:d011 Toshiba America Inc Canvio Desk
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 174c:3074 ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1074 SuperSpeed hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 0781:5567 SanDisk Corp. Cruzer Blade
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 045e:00b0 Microsoft Corp. Digital Media Pro Keyboard
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 046d:c07f Logitech, Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 174c:2074 ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1074 High-Speed hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Try the compilation under a 4.4 kernel instead of a 4.15 kernel.  The timer API has changed -- maybe even a 4.12 kernel would work, but try what the vendor suggests.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `lsusb` We suspect it is an rtl8812au device.

Comment: @ubfan1 How do I compile under a different kernel?

Comment: Drop back to a 16.04.1 release to keep the 4.4 series kernel. I suppose you could add the xenial sources to the /etc/apt/sources.list file, then install an old kernel, but I've never done that.  The 4.4 series kernel is not offered in 18.04 by default.

Comment: so is backwards compatibility not a thing in linux?

Comment: Notice in the duplicate that it's the exact same usb.id 0bda:8812. I just built the package successfully on my 18.04 system.